# How to use Dompdf in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am trying to create/generate pdf from my application, I have planned to use dompdf but I am facing some challenges.

I have downloaded the dompdf from here https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

I have created a file in `/application/libraries` directory `Pdf.php`

`Pdf.php`

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
class Pdf extends DOMPDF
{
    protected function ci()
    {
        return get_instance();
    }

    public function load_view($view, $data = array())
    {
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $html = $this->ci()->load->view($view, $data, TRUE);

        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

        // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
        // $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

        // Render the HTML as PDF
        $dompdf->render();
        $time = time();

        // Output the generated PDF to Browser
        $dompdf->stream("welcome-". $time);
    }
}
```

**Note:** dompdf is in my `/application/thirdparty` directory

And in My **Controller**

```
    function pdf_test(){
        $this->load->library("pdf");
        $this->pdf->load_view('invoice_template');
    }
```

I am getting the below error
`Message: syntax error, unexpected '='`

When I fix above issue i get
`file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.`

Answer (score -1):

Use composer to get the library then in your class add this.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Path to your autoload.php may differ so check it to be sure. Also libraries should be placed within the libraries dir.